# Gráfico con valores multidimensionales

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

Buenas, estoy creando un grafico utilizando la api de google charts el cual tiene que mostrar el progreso de ventas a través de los años.

A continuación el código que estoy usando en la función.

```
function drawChart4() {
    //Llenamos las variables con los array generados mediante php
    var mobile=<?php echo json_encode($mobile);?>; //indicamos si es mobil o no
    var anios=<?php echo json_encode($resultado);?>; //el resultado de un array_unique para recuperar un array de años en los que se ha tenido constancia de alguna venta
    var meses=<?php echo json_encode($meses);?>; // array de meses de Enero a Diciembre
    var ventas=<?php echo json_encode($ventas);?>; // array multidimensional con los valores por cada año-mes

    //inicializo el data
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //agrego las columnas que empleare en el grafico
    data.addColumn('string', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ventas'); //antes no usaba esto, usaba lo que esta mas abajo
    length=0;
    //añado las columnas correctas
    anios.forEach(function(entry) {
        //data.addColumn('number', 'Ventas '+entry); //esto añadira columnas con su año (p.e. Ventas 2017, Ventas 2016, etc.)
        length++;           
    });

    //inicio un bucle para llenar el grafico.
    /*
    E aqui la raiz del problema
    */
    n=0;
    while(n<12){
        data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n]]]);
        n++;
    }
    /*
    Hasta aqui la raiz del problema
    */
    var options = {
        chartArea: {width: '70%'},
        height: 500,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Tiempo (Mensual)'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Cantidad'
        }
    };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Entonces, mi problema radica en el `data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n]]]);` ya que, obviamente solo recorre el array de ventas en la posición `[0][x]`. Si descomento la linia dentro del `anios.forEach` tendre que añadir un nuevo campo, con lo cual deberia quedar:

```
data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], **ventas[anios[1]][n]]]);**
```

He intentado crear un bucle interno dentro del addRows, pero no funciona.

¿Sabéis si hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Os dejo también el fragmento de código php por si os sirve de algo.

```
foreach($resultado as $year){
$n=1;
while($n<=12){
    if($n<10){
        $mes = "0".$n;
    }else{
        $mes = $n;
    }
    $fecha = $year."-".$mes;
    $ticketspositivos = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(r.pvp) FROM $_SESSION[prefijo]rel_ticket_producto r, $_SESSION[prefijo]ticket t WHERE t.idTicket = r.id AND t.fecha LIKE '$fecha-%' AND t.totalTicket > '0'");
    $ticketsnegativos = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(r.pvp) FROM $_SESSION[prefijo]rel_ticket_producto r, $_SESSION[prefijo]ticket t WHERE t.idTicket = r.id AND t.fecha LIKE '$fecha-%' AND t.totalTicket < '0'");
    $facturaspositivas = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(r.pvp) FROM $_SESSION[prefijo]rel_factura_producto r, $_SESSION[prefijo]factura t WHERE t.idFactura = r.id AND t.fecha LIKE '$fecha-%' AND t.totalTicket > '0'");
    $facturasnegativas = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(r.pvp) FROM $_SESSION[prefijo]rel_factura_producto r, $_SESSION[prefijo]factura t WHERE t.idFactura = r.id AND t.fecha LIKE '$fecha-%' AND t.totalTicket < '0'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($ticketspositivos)>0 || mysql_num_rows($ticketsnegativos)>0 || mysql_num_rows($facturaspositivas)>0 || mysql_num_rows($facturasnegativas)>0){
        $ventas[$year][] = (mysql_result($ticketspositivos , 0, 0)+mysql_result($facturaspositivas , 0, 0))-(mysql_result($ticketsnegativos , 0, 0)+mysql_result($facturasnegativas , 0, 0));
    }else{
        $ventas[$year][] = 0;
    }
    $n++;
}
```

**EDITO**

Os muestro un fragmento de código de lo que necesito para aclarar posibles dudas

```
//inicio un bucle para llenar el grafico.
    /*
    E aqui la raiz del problema
    */
    n=0;
    while(n<12){
        if(length == 1){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 2){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 3){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 4){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 5){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n], ventas[anios[4]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 6){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n], ventas[anios[4]][n], ventas[anios[5]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 7){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n], ventas[anios[4]][n], ventas[anios[5]][n], ventas[anios[6]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 8){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n], ventas[anios[4]][n], ventas[anios[5]][n], ventas[anios[6]][n], ventas[anios[7]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 9){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n], ventas[anios[4]][n], ventas[anios[5]][n], ventas[anios[6]][n], ventas[anios[7]][n], ventas[anios[8]][n]]]);
        }else if(length == 10){
            data.addRows([[meses[n], ventas[anios[0]][n], ventas[anios[1]][n], ventas[anios[2]][n], ventas[anios[3]][n], ventas[anios[4]][n], ventas[anios[5]][n], ventas[anios[6]][n], ventas[anios[7]][n], ventas[anios[8]][n], ventas[anios[9]][n]]]);
        }
        n++;
    }
    /*
    Hasta aqui la raiz del problema
    */
```